# Visit to UK to meet business associate as well as friend

Tags: visas, uk, family, greece

I am 59, live in Greece with my Greek wife since 2011. I have permanent resident card that says: "Family member of Greek Citizen"

How can I come to know if my permanent resident card has been issued under Article 10?

Comment: It won't have been, because your wife isn't exercising treaty rights.  If you were living with her in, say, France, then the card would very likely be an article 10 card.  But since you're living in Greece, married to a Greek citizen, national law takes care of everything, and treaty rights are not engaged.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Traveller's Answer, [the page linked above](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card) contains this text which states the wording that should appear on an Article 10 Residence Card.

***Article 10 residence card***

*An Article 10 residence card is a document which is issued under EU law (‘the Free Movement Directive’) by EEA Member States to non-EEA family members of EEA nationals who are exercising free movement rights in another Member State than that of their nationality. For example, the non-EEA spouse of a French national who is living and working in Italy may be issued with an Article 10 residence card by the Italian authorities.*

*An Article 10 residence card should feature the wording “Residence Card of a Family Member of a Union Citizen”.*

*Another document, “Permanent Residence Card of a Family Member of a Union Citizen” issued under Article 20 of the Directive is also acceptable.*

*Documents issued on any other basis, for example (biometric) residence permits issued under the national law of another Member State are not acceptable and do not exempt the holder from the requirement to obtain an EEA family permit.*

The page continues with other information about what documents you should have when presenting yourself at UK Immigration.

Answer (score 0):

Information is provided on the gov.uk site https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card covering:

- what it is
- what you are allowed to do with it
- evidence you need to bring with you to the UK
- applying for a Family Permit

Comment: What if the website goes down. 